# Need clarification to understand an example of manifold (the $n$-sphere)

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is one of the first examples of manifolds, from John M. Lee - *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

[image: sphere-example]

I'm having trouble to understand two things, which I'm gonna show in the simple case of $n=2$. In this case, I'll write $x,y,z$ instead $x^1, x^2, x^3$.

Now we have $f:\mathbb{B}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2-z^2}$, and we have that $U_1^+\cap\mathbb{S}^2$ is "right side" of the sphere. My problems starts when he says this is the graph of the function $$x = f(y,z).$$

**The first problem is:** $f$ is defined in three variables, so it makes no sense to omit some of the variables.

**The second problem is:** how this equation defines a function? It's no clear what should be the input (domain), what should be the output (image) and what is the function itself.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting incorrectly. $\mathbb{B}^2$ is two dimensional, so you will get $f=f(x,y)$, say (or $f(y,z)$ or $f(x,z)$, according to your choice). Assuming you are using the first choice you'll write the sphere as $z=f(x,y)$ with $(x,y) $ chosen from $\mathbb{B}^2$, where $\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ is well defined.

Comment: I'm sorry, but for the sphere, $\mathbb{S}^2 = \{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1\}$ is in the $3$-dimensional space. I always thought the ball $\mathbb{B}^2$ would follow the same description, but with $\leq$ in place of $=$.

Comment: @Integral As a rule of thumb, the superscript in the sphere and the disk are used to denote the dimension they have as a manifold, not the particular space where they are embedded.

Comment: I see... this is new to me. Good to know!

Comment: @Integral You may wonder why use this notation. I'll copy an answer I gave in another question:

"$S^{n}$ has an intrinsic nature. It can be seen in many different topological ways, aside from being an embedded manifold inside $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. It is the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the quotient of the disk by identifying the boundary, the smash product of $S^1 $ $n$ times etc. The invariant thing is: it is always a $n$-manifold. It is therefore more natural to assign the number $n$ in the notation."

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I was, indeed, wondering. Thank you very much for helping.